# How to convert an hexadecimale line in a text file to an array (Python)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file containing in each line an hexadecimal plaintext, My file looks like this:

```
7a8e5dc390781eab8df2c090bf4bebca
dbac0fba55d3d4fc177161bfe24dc7fb
82e5a7a021197f6fbe94a867d4bb3895
850580c1ffec887c5000c9b3a0e6b39d
1526af37ce4b0b4e81f8af0647e37119
bab19c53fd86e6afc933276b286e0c36
b52e53007bebe8877ce569ad2494dd76
44fd87e9b1a40a929ab6135665c22d0f
a88e5141ddc99e0207a9e144f4010a22
58ff597819ea0aa37024a1f1f84c5224
```

I need to convert each line to an array, I mean by that my numpy file must look like this:

```
[ 
[7a,8e,5d,c3,90,78,1e,ab,8d,f2,c0,90,bf,4b,eb,ca],[db,ac,0f,ba,55,d3,d4,fc,17,71,61,bf,e2,4d,c7,fb],
```

.......,
    ]

```
import numpy as np
In_path= "/home/msmache/Bureau/testPlaintext.txt"
Out_path= "/home/msmache/Bureau/testPlaintext.npy"

with open(In_path, "r") as In_f:
    all_arrays = []
    Plaintext=[]
    for line in In_f:
        Plaintext=['{:02x}'.format(b) for b in line]
        all_arrays.append(Plaintext)
    print all_arrays   
    with open(Out_path, "wb") as Out_f:
        np.save(Out_path, all_arrays)
data = np.load(Out_path)
print data
```

This is the error that I have:

```
 Plaintext=['{:02x}'.format(b) for b in line]
 ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Plaintext=['{:02x}'.format(b) for b in line]` cannot work because `for b in line` issues a character of the line, whereas you'd need 2 of them for each iteration.

Also, even if you did that, hexadecimal format applies to integral values, not strings.

My proposal to create `all_arrays`: use simple list slicing double list comprehension:

```
al_arrays = [[l[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(l.strip()),2)] for l in In_f]
```

`all_arrays` yields as expected:

```
[['7a', '8e', '5d', 'c3', '90', '78', '1e', 'ab', '8d', 'f2', 'c0', '90', 'bf',
  '4b', 'eb', 'ca'],
 ['db', 'ac', '0f', 'ba', '55', 'd3', 'd4', 'fc', '17', '71', '61', 'bf', 'e2',
  '4d', 'c7', 'fb'],
 ['82', 'e5', 'a7', 'a0', '21', '19', '7f', '6f', 'be', '94', 'a8', '67', 'd4',
  'bb', '38', '95'],
 ['85', '05', '80', 'c1', 'ff', 'ec', '88', '7c', '50', '00', 'c9', 'b3', 'a0',
  'e6', 'b3', '9d'],
 ['15', '26', 'af', '37', 'ce', '4b', '0b', '4e', '81', 'f8', 'af', '06', '47',
  'e3', '71', '19'],
 ['ba', 'b1', '9c', '53', 'fd', '86', 'e6', 'af', 'c9', '33', '27', '6b', '28',
  '6e', '0c', '36'],
 ['b5', '2e', '53', '00', '7b', 'eb', 'e8', '87', '7c', 'e5', '69', 'ad', '24',
  '94', 'dd', '76'],
 ['44', 'fd', '87', 'e9', 'b1', 'a4', '0a', '92', '9a', 'b6', '13', '56', '65',
  'c2', '2d', '0f'],
 ['a8', '8e', '51', '41', 'dd', 'c9', '9e', '02', '07', 'a9', 'e1', '44', 'f4',
  '01', '0a', '22'],
 ['58', 'ff', '59', '78', '19', 'ea', '0a', 'a3', '70', '24', 'a1', 'f1', 'f8',
  '4c', '52', '24']]
```

Note: if you want numerical values instead of hexadecimal strings, just convert to integer (with base 16)

```
al_arrays = [[int(l[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0,len(l.strip()),2)] for l in In_f]
```

you'll get something like:

```
[[122, 142, 93, 195, 144, 120, 30, 171, 141, 242, 192, 144, 191, 75, 235, 202], [219, 172, 15, 186, 85, ...
```

not hexadecimal, but it doesn't matter for binary conversion.

Comment: How to  avoid the string diplay.? I mean that I need this format: [7a,8e,5d,c3,90,78,1e,ab,8d,f2,c0,90,bf,4b,eb,ca]  , not this one: ['7a', '8e', '5d', 'c3', '90', '78', '1e', 'ab', '8d', 'f2', 'c0', '90', 'bf',
  '4b', 'eb', 'ca'], because I find a problem to convert the numpy file to binary file.

Comment: you mean you want hex numbers? easy, but you'll have `0x` prefix in the list. I think that's what you want: numbers. Let me edit my answer. Edited.

Comment: Thank you very much